# Is it possible to create a Kubernetes RBAC rule to disallow creation of load balancers?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

Using [Kubernetes RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/), we can restrict access to specific resources via specific verbs.

Is there a way to disallow the creation of Services with `type=LoadBalancer` while allowing other types of Services (e.g. `type=NodePort`)?

Sample [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) which we want to disallow:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
  clusterIP: 10.0.171.239
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 192.0.2.127
```

Following is the closest RBAC role we can define - to disallow update operations for all Services (disallowing more than we want):

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: developer
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["services"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible to limit what you asking for.
As you mentioned and you figured it out you can limit access to the API (resources && verbs) but you cant restrict the content of the resource in a simple way.

You will be able to do such a thing if you will write your own hooks in `Admission Control hooks'

`Admission Control hooks` can capture your request and then you check out the content + the user who initiated the request.

It's not a straightforward and nor a simple one, but you will be able to achieve what you asked for.

[image]

---

[image]